# jQuery vs. JavaScript ajax 'POST' functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This **jQuery** code is working:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "file.php",
    data: { json: json },
    complete: function (data) {
        var result = data.responseText;
        console.log(result); // logs 'echo' from PHP file
    }
});
```

This **JavaScript** code is still not working:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "file.php", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        var result = xhr.responseText;
        console.log(result); // supposed to log 'echo' from PHP file
    }
}
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(json));
```

Aren't these two approaches equivalent, or am I missing something?

Suppose 'file.php' looks something like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['json'])){
 $obj = json_decode($_POST['json']);
 //some php operation
 // echo $obj keys and values
}
```

Comment: You must call setRequestHeader() after open() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Comment: The request header might be wrong (might have to be `application/json`) but I'm pretty sure you have to stringify your json: `xmlHttp.send(JSON.stringify(json));`

Comment: @Will good catch, I bet I need to do that, but didn't fix it.

Comment: @Nitin I am calling setRequestHeader('Content-Type','...'); -- was this not what you were thinking?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/what-is-the-correct-json-content-type

Comment: @Will yep, agreed.  I changed application/json and am doing JSON.stringify(json).  See edited code which is still not working.

Comment: @Wagtail I think I misread the question. could you update the question with the new changes? Else try without setRequestHeader

Comment: @Nitin I've done so.

Comment: Hold up...you are sending {json:json} in first case, in 2nd case it is a string without key, or i am wrong...how are you handling the json on server side and what do you see on server side? To answer your question, i think in this case you are sending two different json data.

Comment: @Nitin I've edited it.

Comment: What is not working on it? Do you get an error? Copying and pasting your code directly said json was not defined.  Once I create a json var of var json = {'key' : 'value'}; and pasted your code i nthe console it shot off an ajax request to file.php.

Comment: @JD E would you mind posting that quick?

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PzZLaJ

Comment: if you use your dev tools you can see the ajax request fire off.

Comment: "not working". Specifically, what is not working?

Comment: @JD E yep, I do.  I guess I should work with it and see if json_decode works as well.

Comment: Try this: xhr.send(JSON.stringify({json:json}));

Comment: @Wagtail yeah wagtail when you stringfy json you need to make sure it represents a javascript object.  so by make an object of { 'key' : 'value'} JSON.stringify will make that into a valid json string.

json_decode will work as long as you have a properly formatted json string.

Comment: @JD E Yes I think that was my issue.  Thanks!!

Comment: @Wagtail i like this [site](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/) to help build json, especially in complex objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data : { json: json }
```

gets serialized to '{ "json": {data} }'

```
JSON.stringify(json)
```

gets serialized to '{data}' and there is no "json" key

add your javascript object to a parent wrapper object with a "json" key

```
JSON.stringify({ json: json });
```

Comment: This was the solution for correctly passing the json string to the PHP function for json_decode($_POST['json']) but did not address why the JavaScript was not returning the same console.log() value as the jQuery function.

Comment: if you set the $.ajax dataType to "text" they should be the same.  When its missing $.ajax will guess the return type based on its content and may process the data before returning it to you.   see: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ [settings-dataType]